# Convert heterogeneous numpy array to homogeneous

Tags: python, numpy

Given a numpy array foo with heterogenous elements.
How do I convert a homogeneous slice into a numpy array with multiple dimensions instead of a weird numpy array with nested objects?
Example:

```
foo = np.array([[[1,2,3],[1,2]],[[3,4,5],[3,4]]])
bar = foo[:,0]
bar.shape
Out[9]: (2,)
```

I was expecting bar to have shape (2,3), but instead I get 2 nested objects.
How do I get the equivalent to this:

```
np.array([[1,2,3],[3,4,5]])
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foo` is an object dtype array because the sublists vary in size:

```
In [10]: foo = np.array([[[1,2,3],[1,2]],[[3,4,5],[3,4]]])         
In [11]: foo                                                                                                            
Out[11]: 
array([[list([1, 2, 3]), list([1, 2])],
       [list([3, 4, 5]), list([3, 4])]], dtype=object)                                                                                                                                                                 
In [12]: foo.shape                                                                                                      
Out[12]: (2, 2)
```

Since it is (2,2), you can pick a column, but it will still be object dtype:

```
In [13]: foo[:,0]                                                                                                       
Out[13]: array([list([1, 2, 3]), list([3, 4, 5])], dtype=object)
```

But some version of `concatenate` can join these lists into a new array.  `stack` works nicely here:

```
In [14]: np.stack(foo[:,0])                                                                                             
Out[14]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```

`np.vstack` would also work.  `np.array` doesn't change the object dtype.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to hpaulj's answer final thing to do:

```
np.stack(foo[:,0])
```

`(2, 3)` for shape